# Heuristic for relative browser performance in application

Tags: javascript, performance

I've got some Javascript that scrolls the page when the user drags an element near the edge of the window.  There's a function something like this (simplified):

```
var scroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = $myElement.scrollTop();
    $myElement.scrollTop(scrollTop += delta);
    setTimeout(scroll, 25);
}
```

I'm running into performance issues on older browsers, and I can somewhat mitigate them by reducing the resolution of my `scroll()` function from 25 (as seen above) to 100 or so.

**How can I check if a browser is slower and reduce the resolution?**

I would prefer to avoid user agent sniffing.

Comment: Put it to 50-70 as default and don't try to do something you can't

Answer (score 0):

a human [does not notice "slowness" up until 200-300ms](http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime/stats.php), bump up your timer. no one is going to see that lag within reasonable bounds.

also, pushing the timer to be that fast IS the cause of the problem also. old broswer JS aren't that fast. try opening a task manager and see a spike on your CPU while you drag caused by that very fast timer.

Comment: when I set the timeout to 25 or 15 the change is noticeably smoother.  try it for yourself on a table with 300-500 rows.  i understand that computationally-intensive tasks push the CPU :)  i'm just curious if there's a good way to get a feel for that in the code so i can adjust accordingly.

Comment: *"How can I check if a browser is slower and reduce the resolution?"* - why not *"make it work on all browsers"*?

Comment: you seem like you would make a good QA engineer.  it's ok, it works in all browsers :)  i'd like to progressively enhance the user experience on more modern browsers though.

Comment: you can alternatively look under the hood of jQuery and check on `.animate()` method. i use it for scrolling elements and it works smoothly on IE6.